# Find the volume of the function $y=\frac{6}{x}$

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

Consider the function $y=\frac{6}{x}$ bounded by $y=0$, $x=1$,and $x=3$ and is rotated around the $x$-axis.

Using the disk method I setup the integral as 
$$\pi\int_1^33^2-\left(\frac{6}{x} \right)^2dx $$
solving gave me $42\pi$ but the answer should be $24\pi$, my question is where did I mess up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral should be

$$\pi\int_1^3 \left(\frac{6}{x} \right)^2dx =24\pi $$

where $6/x$ is the radius of the disk at $x$. Also note the volume revolves around $x$-axis, not $y$.

Answer (score 3):

The integrand is incorrect. It should be just $(\frac{6}{x})^2$. There's no reason to subtract this from $3^2$.